# ASP.NET Core MVC C# - Show Custom Popup Error Message When the Page Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, timeout

I have ASP.NET Core MVC Application and I want to set the timeout for a page to say 60 seconds and if a page keeps loading for 60 seconds or more then show the timeout error message in a popup window saying "The site appears to be taking too long to load this page."

I have gone through the setting up timeout middleware in ASP.NET Core C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0

But not sure how we can customise to show popup error message.

Comment: Just short-circuit the response in your middleware to return a custom timeout response

Comment: @MateusZampol Can you please give me a small example of short-circuiting the middleware to return a custom message?

Answer (score 1):

To show the customize pop up message you could use the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            if (!document.readyState === "complete") {
                alert("The site appears to be taking too long to load this page.");
            }
        }, 60000); 

        document.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        };
    };
</script>
```